# What is the SQL Standard method of doing LIMIT OFFSET?

Tags: postgresql, sql-standard, offset-fetch

I know `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` are pretty common but unstandardized methods to page through a result set. I know there is a standardized method, but I can never find this when I'm going to look it up,

- The [PostgreSQL `LIMIT/OFFSET` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html) don't link to it,
- The [PostgreSQL `FETCH` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html) don't link to it either.

I know it's not either of them. What is the SQL Standard and PostgreSQL syntax for `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SQL 2011 Spec

The syntax in the spec is defined as,

```
<query expression> ::=
  [ <with clause> ] <query expression body>
  [ <order by clause> ] [ <result offset clause> ] [ <fetch first clause> ]
```

You can see here that `<result offset clause>` and the `<fetch first clause>` are both optional and stand by themselves, moving on

```
<result offset clause> ::=
  OFFSET <offset row count> { ROW | ROWS }

<fetch first clause> ::=
  FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ <fetch first quantity> ] { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES }

<fetch first quantity> ::=
  <fetch first row count>
  | <fetch first percentage>

<offset row count> ::=
  <simple value specification>

<fetch first row count> ::=
  <simple value specification>

<fetch first percentage> ::=
  <simple value specification> PERCENT

<simple value specification> ::=
  <literal>
  | <host parameter name>
  | <SQL parameter reference>
  | <embedded variable name>
```

## RDBMS-Specific

### PostgreSQL

The SQL:2011 Spec supports a bit [more than PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html), namely a `WITH TIES` option (F867) and the ability to specify `PERCENT` option (F866). The query is defined as,

PostgreSQL only documents this, AFAIK, in [`SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html),

```
SELECT
...
[ OFFSET start [ ROW | ROWS ] ]
[ FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ count ] { ROW | ROWS } ONLY ]
```

For more information aside from PostgreSQL, and the spec see the [tag-info for `offset-fetch`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/offset-fetch/info)